# Running python code as a service on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: python, service, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a python script which collects data from Twitter and stores into MongoDb. I need to run this code on the server as a service.

However, only 2 users can remain logged into the server at any given time and therefore If I log out my account, the python script would stop working and data collection will stop.

My question is - How can I run this script as a service on the server such that it keeps running irrespective of whichever user is logged in?

Comment: You can use python's win32 extension modules for this. Check out the `win32serviceutil` module and search the net for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler is the easiest solution I know of. You can use it to run the code at startup as the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user and automatically restart on failure. In case you need it, there's a basic overview of Task Scheduler [here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx)